# I want to find 2's complement of 0000

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation

I want to design a hardware which will give 2's complement of input 4-bit binary number. But i stuck at very first input: 0000.Because the method i generally use to find 2's complement is to first find 1's complement of binary number and then adding 1 into it.But if I do same with 0000, then it will give me 5-bit number 10000. that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *cut off* the upper bits if you're working with an `n`-bit value. The two's complement of the four-bit `0000` is the last four bits of `10000`, or `0000`. Otherwise the ones' complement of `100` would be:

```
1111111111...ad infinitum...1111111011
```

rather than the correct `011`.

That (the cutting off of extraneous bits) makes sense since the negation of zero is zero (though that could be arguable for ones' complement or sign-magnitude, where `-0` is a distinct possibility).

Answer (score 1):

If you design hardware, see hardware circuits for produce 4-bit complement number.[image]